# Change values in a dataframe depending on other dataframe

Tags: python

I have two data set as follows

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40],
                            [11, 21, 31, 41]]), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([0, 1, 0, 1]).reshape(1, -1), columns =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

What I want is; If any item of `df2` is greater than `0.5`, the same Items of `df1` will be `0` after running the code the `df1` will be

```py
print(df)
```

```
A  B  C  D
10 0 30 0
11 0 31 0
```

I tried using

```
df1[df2>= 0.5] = 0
```

Comment: To avoid any error in `df2`, the shape should be changed, which I did use `.reshape(a, b)` in `numpy`

Comment: Kindly accept the edits, have corrected them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `pandas.DataFrame.where()`, after you brought `df2` to the same shape as `df1`. Please understand that `df.where()` replaces all values if the condition **does not** match, so this is the reson why `>=` is changed to `<`.

```
df1 = df1.where(df2<0.5, 0)

>>> df1
    A  B   C  D
0  10  0  30  0
1  11  0  31  0
```

If you have problems to extend `df2`, you can use this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0, 1]], columns =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
>>>df2
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1

n = 1 # df1.shape[0] - 1
df2 = df2.append([df2.loc[0,:]]*n,ignore_index=True)

>>> df2
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both of the data frames have the same number of columns, `where()` method in pandas data frame can get the job done.
i.e

```py
>>> df1.where(df2 < 0.5)
```

```
      A   B     C   D
  0  10.0 NaN  30.0 NaN
  1   NaN NaN   NaN NaN
```

By default, if the condition evaluated to `False` in the `where()` method, the position will be replaced with `NaN` but not `inplace`. We can change that by changing the `other` argument from it's default value to `0` and to make the changes in-place we set `inplace=True`.

```py
>>> df1.where(df2 < 0.5, other=0, inplace=True)
>>> df1
```

```
    A  B   C  D
0  10  0  30  0
1   0  0   0  0
```